# How to pass a variable log as an argument to a script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I am trying to pass a log as an argument to a script that does the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
filter(){

grep -E "ERROR|FATAL|WARN|Caused|^[[:space:]]" /app/me/logs/$1

}

#read varName

filter > /app/me/logs/${1}.filtered

cat /app/me/logs/${1}.filtered
```

but it is not outputting anything, and the log file it creates has nothing in it. The command I pass it is like this:

```
>>> log_filter test.log
```

log_filter is the name of the script and test.log is the argument log I want to filter
as you can see I wrote "read varName" this works if I pass varName instead of $1 into each one, but I don't want that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
filter > /app/me/logs/${1}.filtered
```

to:

```
filter "$@" > "/app/me/logs/${1}.filtered"
```

Why? Each function has its own list of positional parameters. You need to supply the list of positional parameters to the function you are calling.

In other words:
The `$1` inside the function `filter` is not the same as the `$1` in the main script.

If just one parameter is what you need:

```
filter "$1" > "/app/me/logs/${1}.filtered"
```

should be just enough.

Comment: Ohhh yeaaah of course!!!! Thanks a lot! :)